# Translate a curl request in rest::client Perl

Tags: rest, perl

This curl line works perfectly :

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k -d "{\"UserName\":\"test\",\"Password\":\"test\"}" -X POST "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/redfish/v1/SessionService/Sessions"
```

but when trying to translate into Perl, I've a http 500 error code in response.

Here an excerpt of my code :

```
$CLIENT=REST::Client->new(
{
    host => $HOSTURL,
    timeout => 300,
}
);
# Formatage de la requete
$URL = "/redfish/v1/SessionService/Sessions";
$ACTION = "POST";
%CONTENT_JSON = (
    'UserName' => 'test',
    'Password' => 'test'
);   
%SESS_HEADERS = (
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
);
$CONTENT_JSON = encode_json(\%CONTENT_JSON);
# Lancement de la requete
print Dumper $ACTION,$URL,$CONTENT_JSON,\%SESS_HEADERS;
$CLIENT->request($ACTION,$URL,$CONTENT_JSON,\%SESS_HEADERS);
$REPCODE = $CLIENT->responseCode();
print Dumper $REPCODE;
print Dumper $CLIENT->responseContent();
exit;
```

and the results :

```
$VAR1 = 'POST';
$VAR2 = '/redfish/v1/SessionService/Sessions';
$VAR3 = '{"UserName":"test","Password":"test"}';
$VAR4 = {
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    };
$VAR1 = 500;
$VAR1 = 'Can\'t connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
```

So, where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a clue:

> ```
> $VAR1 = 'Can\'t connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
> ```

Are you sure that you've got the correct domain name? And does the resource work over HTTPS?

Oh and I bet REST::Client uses LWP::UserAgent, so you'll need [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https) installed as well.

Comment: Yes, it works with curl on the same server. But I forgot the LWP::UserAgent, after including it I had to turn off ssl verification with $ENV{'PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME'} = 0;